# How to set a default selected option in PHP for a dropdown menu based on a specific condition?

Tags: php, sql

I have a PHP code that generates a dropdown menu from a MySQL database. The dropdown menu is populated with options retrieved from the "inventory" table. I want to set a default selected option based on a specific condition. For example, if the `$_GET['in_id']` is set, I want the corresponding option with that `In_id` to be selected by default when the dropdown is rendered.

Here is the PHP code I'm using to generate the dropdown:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `inventory`";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo '<option value="'.$fetch['In_id'].'">'.$fetch['In_name'].'</option>';
}

if (isset($_GET['in_id'])){
    $in_id = $_GET['in_id'];
    $sql_in = "SELECT * FROM `inventory` WHERE In_id='$in_id'";
    $query_in = mysql_query($sql_in);
    $fetch_in = mysql_fetch_array($query_in);
}
```

How can I modify this code to set a default selected option based on the `$_GET['in_id']` value?

Comment: Note: Your code is vulnerable to SQL-injection, if you didn't know that. And, you're missing a quote at the end of the last `echo` statement in your first code

Comment: Could you please help?

Comment: I don't understand the question. "What should I do?" To achieve what? You REALLY need to use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection - see http://xkcd.com/327/ . Other than that you need to explain what you intend to do and why/how the above doesn't so it, if you want help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your while loop same as below:

```
 while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  $in_id = $_GET['in_id'];
  $sel = '';
  if($in_id == $fetch['In_id']){
        $sel = 'selected="selected"';
  }
  echo '<option value="'.$fetch['In_id'].'" '.$sel.'>'.$fetch['In_name'].';}
```